# angularjs post data with $http to laravel 5.4

Tags: php, angularjs, json, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I try to send data to laravel api in this route:

```
Route::post('/checkform',['uses' => 'SaveurController@checkform'] );
```

In angular I get all the data needed and send it in this function `ng-submit="submitForm()"`

In my controller :

```
$scope.submitForm = function() {
serviceAjax.postForm({form:$scope.formData,cart:this.productData,options:options}).then(function (response) {
            console.log({data :response.config.data});
            return {data :response.config.data};

        });
}
```

and the service is:

```
.factory('serviceAjax', function ($http, $q) {
postForm:function (data) {
                return $http.post('http://livrer/api/checkform',data);
            }
)};
```

In my console I get the response after success:

```
Object {data: Object}
data:Object
cart:Object
form:Object
options:Object
```

they value are like expected and exist in **Request payload**:

```
{form: {phone: "246 46"}, cart: {shipping: 15, taxRate: 20, tax: null,…},…}
cart
:
{shipping: 15, taxRate: 20, tax: null,…}
form
:
{phone: "246 46"}
options
:
{totalTTC: 93, total: 65}
```

But in laravel side I cant access this value I try in the SaveurController@checkform :

```
    public function checkform(Request $request){
        dd($request->input('data'));//is empty
    dd($request->json()->all());//nothing to
    if(!Session::has('json')){
                Session(['json' => $request->input('data')]);
    } // nothing to display

}
```

I dont know what I miss and how can I debug this post data to see they structure to persist this data in database.
Thank you.

Comment: hi i don't know lavarel .. but maybe the prblem is you're tryng to access data which is a sub-object of your post obj .. try to check in developer trools (chrome tab network) if in the post request you see the data in the payload of the POST request ..and if so .. try to name your obj send to back end ..something like var  myObj ={form:$scope.formData,cart:this.productData,options:options};  serviceAjax.postForm(myObj) and then in your back end controller acces it as input('myObj')

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi thank you for your anwsers they exist in the payload, I edit my question .